# Cannot import Numpy and Pandas

Tags: python, pip, numpy, pandas

I have installed numpy and pandas using pip. After executing my python code it shows the following error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "demo.py", line 1, in <module>
    import numpy as np
  File "/home/tauhid/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/numpy/__init__.py", line 142, in <module>
    from . import core
  File "/home/tauhid/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/numpy/core/__init__.py", line 59, in <module>
    from . import numeric
  File "/home/tauhid/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/numpy/core/numeric.py", line 3093, in <module>
    from . import fromnumeric
  File "/home/tauhid/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/numpy/core/fromnumeric.py", line 17, in <module>
    from . import _methods
  File "/home/tauhid/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/numpy/core/_methods.py", line 158, in <module>
    _NDARRAY_ARRAY_FUNCTION = mu.ndarray.__array_function__
AttributeError: type object 'numpy.ndarray' has no attribute '__array_function__'
```

I have tried uninstalling and reinstalling the packages, but same error reoccurs.

Answer (score 1):

The `import numpy as np, pandas` command won't work unless you run it with Python 3.x, because you installed numpy and pandas for Python 3.6. To install Numpy and Pandas for Python 2.7 open the terminal and type:

```
sudo apt install python-numpy # 20.04 and earlier
sudo apt install python-pandas # 18.04 and earlier
```

The equivalent of the above command for Python 3.x is:

```
sudo apt install python3-numpy python3-pandas
```

Numpy and Pandas are currently installed locally in the home directory, not globally. To install the latest stable versions of Numpy and Pandas globally with pip run this command:

```
sudo python3 -m pip install numpy pandas
```

Before you make a hasty decision to install Numpy and Pandas globally with pip, remember that Numpy and Pandas packages are in the default Ubuntu repositories too.

Answer (score -1):

Try this:

```
sudo python -m pip install --upgrade numpy
sudo python -m pip install --upgrade scipy
```